# Table of different colors in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, colors

I would like to have a table containing various colors. The subsequent colors should differ significantly. What would be the best approach to fill considerably large table according to that? I want to use a large number of different colors before any repetition of similar colors.

Comment: Define "large", define "differ significantly"?

Comment: large, e.g. 1000 colors. differ significantly - I want to get e.g. red, blue, green colors rather than red, dark red, violet ;-) Shortly, I want to avoid repeating of similar colors.

Comment: I had good result using the HSL/HSV colors and converting them back to  RGB. You keep SL/SV fixed and go through H values.

Comment: @xanatos, that is exactly what I am doing right now :-) However I can't assure that subsequent colors are significantly different. How do you choose your subsequent H values?

Comment: @Jamie You subdivide the H space in 1000 parts... But then your colors would be too much similar. It's complex to have 1000 colors different enough, you know?

Comment: @xanatos, it was just an example with 1000 colors ;-)

Comment: @Jamie In the end if your H scale is 0-1, you subdivide in 1000 parts. You could try to subdivide it in only (for example) 250 parts and have 2 different values for S and 2 different values for L (so 250 * (2 * 2) * (2 * 2))... I see that in the LAB/CIELAB color space the pythagorean distance is equal to the subjective (by the observer) distance of two colors. So in that space you could simply create N points all at the same distance between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution (a Silverlight compatible one at that).

```
    IEnumerable<Color> VaryingColors(int seedIndex)
    {
        int maxValue = 1 << 24;
        int index = seedIndex % maxValue;

        while (true)
        {
            byte r = 0;
            byte g = 0;
            byte b = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                if ((index & (1 << i)) != 0)
                {
                    switch (i % 3)
                    {
                        case 0: r |= (byte)(1 << (23 - i) / 3); break;
                        case 1: g |= (byte)(1 << (23 - i) / 3); break;
                        case 2: b |= (byte)(1 << (23 - i) / 3); break;
                    }
                }
            }

            yield return Color.FromArgb(0xFF, r, g, b);

            index = (index + 1) % maxValue;
        }
    }
```

Here is a usage example.  Create a new Silverlight application and add a `ListBox` the MainPage.xaml like this:-

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="200" Height="20" Fill="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In the MainPage.Xaml.cs constructor include code like this:-

```
   DataContext = VaryingColors(0).Take(100).Select(c => new SolidColorBrush(c));
```

The color generator will generate all 16 Million possible colors and by manipulating the most significant bits of the R G B components first.  May need a little more work there are some occurances of adjacent colors being more similar than the rest of the sequence although they are always discernably different.

One enhancement might be to add a filter on the sequence to discard colors that are too dark or have very low saturation.  In fact another filter might be added to discard a color that has a hue close to the previous color in the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Gridview in C# and then use the

```
GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

method to change the background colour of the cells to whatever color you need.

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#EE3333"); // makes the 4th cell red
    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen; // Makes the whole row Green
    }
```

using this method you can colour the cells to your liking using RGB colours.

http://rgbchart.com/

http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/

Comment: Sorry, I think you didn't unsderstand my question :-)